# Replacing values with LINQ in a list with the previous value matching some criterion

Tags: linq

I have produced a list of two values.

```
Id Value
10  0 
11  1 
12  2 
13  3 
14 -1 
15 -1 
16  6 
17 -1 
18  8 
19  9
```

I would like all `-1` values to be replaced with the previous not `-1` value such that I end up with the list

```
Id Value
10  0 
11  1 
12  2 
13  3 
14  3 
15  3 
16  6 
17  6 
18  8 
19  9
```

Is there a cool way of doing this in LINQ?

Comment: Why not simple `foreach`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yet another variant - use Aggregate extension like this

```
list = list.Aggregate(new List<YourObjectClass>(), (a, b) =>
    {
        if (b.Value == -1 && a.Count>0)
            b.Value = a.Last().Value;

        a.Add(b);
        return a;
    });
```

Comment: I like this one. Very clean.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to access previous elements with LINQ a loop might be more appropriate (readable,efficient).

However (`Obj` is your class):

```
list = list.Select((x, index) => 
{
    if (index != 0 && x.Value == -1)
    {
        x.Value = list.Take(index)
            .Where(xPrev => xPrev.Value != -1)
            .Select(xPrev => xPrev.Value)
            .DefaultIfEmpty(int.MinValue)
            .Last();
    }
    return x;
}).ToList();
```

Note that this does not ensure that you get a different value than -1 since i'm just selecting the previous.

Comment: `list[index - 1]` does not work if you have several -1 in a row.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This produces a rather strange result for me: (0,0,0,0,-1,-1,8,-1,9,9)

Comment: Aaaa, i see. `x.Value == -1` instead of `x.Value != -1`.

Comment: @lejon: Yes, i have noticed it myself  a second ago. That was a leftover of my first approach.

Comment: @lejon: But you've noticed that i've edited my answer? Vladimir has already mentioned the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
var lastValue = -1;
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (item.Value == -1)
    {
        item.Value = lastValue;
    }
    else
    {
        lastValue = item.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: @lejon: it's possible (i've edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20118569/284240)) but not the best approach. Indices and LINQ don't play well together.

Comment: @VladimirFrolov It's funny, it works in LinqPad, but not in VS - "readonly local variable cannot be used as an assignment target"